# Installing DNVM with Chef

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, chef-infra

I am attempting to install the DNVM via Chef. This is also my first time with chef.

The ASP.NET 5 site says to run this at a command prompt.

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}"
```

The result of that file is the contents I dumped into my chef recipe.

```
powershell_script "Install DNVM" do
code <<-EOH
Write-Host "Starting DNVM Install"
$tempPath = Join-Path $env:TEMP "dnvminstall"
$dnvmPs1Path = Join-Path $tempPath "dnvm.ps1"
$dnvmCmdPath = Join-Path $tempPath "dnvm.cmd"

Write-Host "Using temporary directory: $tempPath"
if (!(Test-Path $tempPath)) { md $tempPath | Out-Null }


$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy
$webClient.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
Write-Host "Downloading DNVM.ps1 to $dnvmPs1Path"
$webClient.DownloadFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvm.ps1', $dnvmPs1Path)
Write-Host "Downloading DNVM.cmd to $dnvmCmdPath"
$webClient.DownloadFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvm.cmd', $dnvmCmdPath)
Write-Host "Installing DNVM"        
& $dnvmCmdPath setup
EOH
only_if { ENV['DNX_HOME'] == nil}
end
```

When I run "kitchen converge", it returns success. Digging into the windows VM I can see that it made a "dnvminstall" directory and downloaded the dnvm.ps1 and dnvm.cmd files, but did not install the DNVM and finished way to quickly. Running the above powershell script does install the DNVM with no errors.

I also tried just the "execute" chef command to run the first statement, the , it also downloaded the appropriate files but also didn't install them.

Comment: Try turning the log level up to debug (`chef-client -l debug`) to see the command output, and check it for errors/warnings.

Comment: Tried it, and it worked, but when i push the recipe to the box it doesn't. Current guess is that the power shell script when running a bat file causes it to enter an interactive mode that doesn't work when chef runs it without a UI.

Comment: @Josh - were you able to figure this out ? as I am having the same issue. When I run it the second time it works.